# True or False: The pattern of the residuals vs predicted values and the residuals vs a predictor based on a 2nd order model are exactly the same

Tags: self-study, descriptive-statistics, residuals

I'm currently working on an assignment for a course in Statistics and was wondering anyones thoughts on this. My friends and I keep going back and forth on which one it is. I think it's true for the pattern but I don't understand why that would be the case.

True or False: The pattern of the residuals vs predicted values and the residuals vs a predictor based on a 2nd order model are exactly the same.

What I have thought of so far is that the patterns would be the same because of the fact that it is the only variable within the model.

I don't have a clue so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Why not make up some data and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

**False**

If the pattern of residuals vs. predicted values is the same as residuals vs. an individual predictor, there must be a linear relationship between the predictor and the predicted values. If this relationship between predictor and prediction is non-linear, then the two graphs will have different shapes. Because this is a second-order model, we know that the relationship between predictor and prediction is non-linear. Therefore, the pattern of residuals vs. predicted values is not the same as residuals vs. a predictor - essentially, you're taking the residuals vs. predictor graph, and performing a non-linear transformation of one of the axes (because the predictor to prediction transformation is non-linear).